# vscode source control providers add repo

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project using git submodules (despite their shortcomings) and I have a new submodule added, but in vscode, I cannot get it to appear in my list of repos in the source control pane under "Source Control Providers"...

I've tried doing CMD+SHIFT+P and running "Git: initialize new repo"  - and tried "Git: clone new repo" on my co-workers machine, I just tried totally deleting vscode with AppCleaner, after backing up with Settings Sync, restarting machine and then installing a fresh copy of vscode, but even that didn't seem to work.

tried doing some other stuff to get it to be recognized... no go.. Adding to workspace just added another top level folder in the file browser and nothing happened to source control pane...

Answer (score 3):

Open Ctrl + Shift + P, and select "Git: Open Repository" item.
That will open up a folder explorer.
And then you can select the root folder of the Git repo.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up open my git submodule directory in it's own vscode window (`cd src/submodule1 && code .`) and then changed some code there, viewed the changes in the source control panel, and wa-la, I went back to my main window, and it appeared in the "Source Control Providers".